# find control inside datalist on page load

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I want to find an item in the datalist on page load method this is my code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //some code here

    for (int i = 0; i < count  ; i++)
    {
        LinkButton LinkButton6 = (LinkButton)sender;
        DataListItem item = (DataListItem)LinkButton6.NamingContainer;
        LinkButton lnkbtn6 = (LinkButton)DataList1.Items[item.ItemIndex].FindControl("LinkButton6");  
     }  
 }
```

but this error appears to me :Unable to cast object of type 'ASP.default2_aspx' to type   'System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton'.

Comment: `Page_Load` is not an event triggered by LinkButton so sender cannot be a LinkButton. It is a Page event.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve that you want to find item in page load?

Comment: I want to change the text of the linkbutton in the datalist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Page_Load` is not an event triggered by LinkButton so sender cannot be a LinkButton. It is a Page event. Use `OnItemDataBound` instead

Markup

```
<asp:DataList OnItemDataBound="DataList1_OnItemDataBound" runat="server" ID="MdataList">
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="LinkButton6" Text="Text"></asp:LinkButton>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

Codebehind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

protected void DataList1_OnItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton lnkBtn6 = (LinkButton)e.Item.FindControl("LinkButton6");
    lnkBtn6.Text = "Some Text Here";
}
```

Comment: Yes. Page load should be separate

Answer (score 0):

On this line:

```
LinkButton LinkButton6 = (LinkButton)sender;
```

the `sender` object is the `Page`, not `LinkButton`, isn't it?